# Swift ISO-8601 date formatting with iOS7

Tags: ios, date, swift, locale

I really need your help guys. The following piece of code works fine in a Swift Playgound and with any iOS8 or 8.1 simulator. But with iOS7 and 7.1, the NSDate object is always set to nil.

The object dateString contains a JSON string (ISO 8601 format) like  **2015-02-28T20:15:00+0100**
I'm trying to convert this date string into a NSDate object with the following code :

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ"
if let dateString = (json as NSDictionary).valueForKey("dateAndTime") as? String
{
   let dateObject = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}
```

Where's my mistake ? I'm getting confused!
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your  time zone offset, your date format is not proper for that. Use the following format,

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

Comment: Amazing. Many thanks. I was getting crazy. By the way, I still don't understand why ut worked fine with iOS8.

Comment: Y should only be used for WeekOfYear.

Comment: I got the answer thanks. The problem was effectively with the "...zzz" format I was using. "...ZZZZZ" works fine. With the "...zzz" format, dateFromString always gave nil. Thanks guys for your help.