# convert json marshall time to nsdate

Tags: swift, go, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I marshall `time.Now()` to JSON object it gives result as `"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"` but printing `time.Now` gives `2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC`. Why are they different. What are `T` and `Z`. Also how can I convert it to swift NSDate object according to [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) table?

Comment: have you even tried to search for it like for example "Z in timezone"?

Comment: T is just used to separate Time from fate. Z is the timezone (Zulu).

Comment: @MarioZannone Is there a need for `T`? why not just space?

Comment: It's an ISO standard (ISO8601)

Comment: Anyway, in order to convert to an NSDate have a look at the NSDateFormatter documentation and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791771/swift-iso-8601-date-formatting-with-ios7)

Comment: @MarioZannone I did try. The correct format looked like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX` but it doesn't work. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ` didn't work either. The orijinal string I'm working on is `2015-07-21T05:34:00.448575Z`

Comment: Look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269378/swift-converting-json-date-to-swift-compatible-date)

Comment: @MarioZannone Thank you this was it. You could post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of those values is irrelevant, they're part of that format (ISO8601). There are a couple approaches to this. One is to define a custom `MarshalJSON()` method for time or your struct and use it to format the date, the other is to represent it as a string in your struct in the first place so that when the default implementation executes you get the result you're looking for.

The method you'll ultimately need to use is; `time.Format(format string)`
The golang docs show this example for using it;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // layout shows by example how the reference time should be represented.
    const layout = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
    t := time.Date(2009, time.November, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
    fmt.Println(t.UTC().Format(layout))
}
```

The medium date format in that link for example would use the string `"Jan. 2, 2006"`

Comment: But why is the marshalled time and the printed time different?

Comment: @Thellimist because when marshal the json, the package uses reflection to iterate the types properties and format them for json. The a `time.Date` is formatted it's using the default format string. What I was trying to explain is that you can either avoid that by using a string in the struct you marshal, or you can implement that method so that when the `time.Date` is formatted it's using one of the ones you need.

Comment: I understood your answer. I was wondering why they were different also. Wish I had asked as a separate question :) While reflection why doesn't it converts as a default format string